# C programming: SIGABRT 134 error; am I freeing this memory correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, free

I have a nested datastructure as such (these are the initalizations):

```
Interval *newInterval(int b, int e, int m){
    static Interval i;
    i.b = b;
    i.e = e;
    i.m = m;
    return &i;
}
Signal *newSignal(int size){
    static Signal s;
    s.intervals = malloc(size * sizeof(Interval));
    s.top = 0;
    s.size = size;
    return &s;
}

Stack *newStack(int size){
    static Stack st;
    st.signals = malloc(size * sizeof(Signal));
    st.top = 0;
    st.size = size;
    return &st;
}
```

**How they the data is structured:** Multiple Interval struct pointers are stored in the 'intervals' array of each Signal struct. Each Signal struct pointer is stored in the 'signals' array of a Stack struct (there will always only be one).

```
        -> [Signal 0] -> [Interval 0][Interval 1][Interval 2]...
[Stack] -> [Signal 1] -> [Interval 0][Interval 1]
        -> [Signal 2] -> [Interval 0][Interval 1][Interval 2]...
```

**How I try to access and free data:** I have two functions that print out data from within the structures, and attempt to free the memory allocated using malloc (and realloc). However I seem to be getting a SIGABRT (error 134). I suppose this is because of how I free the memory; but I don't know what to do!

```
    void pop(Signal *s, int n){
    if(n < s->top) {
        printf("[%d,%d)@%d ", s->intervals[n].b, s->intervals[n].e, s->intervals[n].m);
        pop(s,n+1);
    }
    else {
        free(s->intervals);
    }
}

void printIntervals(Stack *st){
    for(int i=0; i<st->top; i++){
        pop(&(st->signals[i]), 0);
        printf("\n");
        free(&(st->signals[i]));
    }
}
```

> **1.** printIntervals is called once, and in turn calls the pop function for each signal.
>
> **2.** The pop function recursively prints out each interval struct, until the array containing intervals is empty, at which point I
>   attempt to free the intervals array from the signal.
>
> **3.** At this point pop finishes, and the flow goes back to printIntervals. Here, I attempt to free the signals array as there's
>   nothing left to print, and the loop moves on to print the next signal
>   from the Stack.

Is the way I free memory incorrect? How can I fix the memory error? Thank you.

Comment: `static Stack st;` followed by `st.signals = malloc()` is very bad, and easily a memory leak. Please ready and understand the meaning of `static` in the context you've used it. It appears that you wanted to avoid `malloc()`ing and for that you did something that is very very wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you `free()` the multiple `Stack` pointers — *to take one as an examle* — you are really always freeing the same pointer.

When you declare the structure as `static` in the function scope it's only initialized once, subsequent calls will affect the pointer that you returned initially and thus using `malloc()` on one member effectively makes all your pointers point to the same `malloc()`ed area. So the previous pointer it pointed to is now lost and you can't free it.

Moreover, you can't `free()` something that wasn't returned by `malloc()`. Specially it's supicious and porbably wrong to call `free()` on a pointer that is actually the result of evaluating the `&` address of operator.

Your code should probably be fixed as follows,

```
Interval *
newInterval(int b, int e, int m)
{
    Interval *interval;
    interval = malloc(sizeof(*interval));
    if (interval == NULL)
        return NULL;
    interval->b = b;
    interval->e = e;
    interval->m = m;
    return interval;
}

Signal *
newSignal(int size)
{
    Signal *signal;
    signal = malloc(sizeof(*signal));
    if (signal == NULL)
        return NULL;
    signal->intervals = malloc(size * sizeof(*signal->intervals));
    if (signal->intervals == NULL) {
        free(signal);
        return NULL;
    }
    signal->top = 0;
    signal->size = size;
    return signal;
}

Stack *
newStack(int size)
{
    Stack *stack;
    stack = malloc(sizeof(*stack));
    if (stack == NULL)
        return NULL;
    stack->signals = malloc(size * sizeof(*stack->signals));
    if (stack->signals == NULL) {
        free(stack);
        return NULL;
    }
    stack->top = 0;
    stack->size = size;
    return stack;
}
```

Also, good design is important and a function called `print*` shall not free anything at all, in fact you should avoid freeing memory in a given context that was allocated in a different context.

Comment: Re. the statement "Specially it's explicitly wrong to call free() on a pointer that is actually the result of evaluating the & address of operator.": `char *p = malloc(10); free(&p[0]);` would work just fine for example. It's not the address-of but whether it yields the correct pointer that matters.